# Cleaning up Erlang code for a text editor

Tags: beginner, erlang, text-editor

On Monday and Tuesday I started learning Erlang through the [Erlang Koans](https://github.com/patrickgombert/erlang-koans), and around Wednesday night I decided to use my newfound knowledge to implement a simple text editor (Akin to ed(1)). Currently I have the following (also on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/snippets/20414)):

```
-module(text).
-compile(export_all).

%% State => {file, buffer, cursor}
main() ->
  {ok, Arg} = init:get_argument(f),
  Name = lists:nth(1, lists:nth(1, Arg)),
  main(Name).

main (String) ->
  {ok, File} = file:open(String, [read, write]),
  {ok, Buffer, Lines} = buffer(File),
  io:fwrite("~B lines read of ~s~n", [Lines, String]),
  loop({File, Buffer, 1}).

loop(State) ->
  NewState = command(State),
  case NewState of
    {_, _, _} -> loop(NewState);
    _ -> ok
    end.

append(Buffer, Line) ->
  erlang:insert_element(tuple_size(Buffer)+1, Buffer, Line).

buffer(File) ->
  buffer(File, {}).
buffer(File, Buffer) ->
  Line = io:get_line(File, ""),
  case Line of
    eof -> {ok, Buffer, tuple_size(Buffer)};
    {error, Description} -> {error, Description};
    _ -> buffer(File, append(Buffer, Line))
    end.

put(stdout, {_, {}, _}, _) ->
  'nothing to write';
put(stdout, {_, Buffer, _}, Line) ->
  io:fwrite(" ~s", [element(Line, Buffer)]);
put(file, {File, Buffer, _}, Line) ->
  io:fwrite(File, "~s", [element(Line, Buffer)]).

%% Ew Ew Ew Ew Ew
write_buffer(stdout, {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  write_buffer(stdout, {File, Buffer, Pos}, 1, tuple_size(Buffer)).
write_buffer({File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  file:position(File, bof),
  write_buffer(file, {File, Buffer, Pos}, 1, tuple_size(Buffer)).

write_buffer(Out, State, N, Length) when N =< Length ->
  put(Out, State, N),
  write_buffer(Out, State, N+1, Length);
write_buffer(_, {File, {}, Pos}, _, _) ->
  file:truncate(File),
  {File, {}, Pos};
write_buffer(_, State, _, _) ->
  State.

put_cursor(N, {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  put_cursor(Pos, Pos+N, {File, Buffer, Pos}).
put_cursor(Current, End, State) when Current < End ->
  put(stdout, State, Current),
  put_cursor(Current+1, End, State);
put_cursor(_, _, State) ->
  State.

is_stop(Line) ->
  (string:len(Line) == 2) and (string:substr(Line, 1, 1) == ".").

input() ->
  Line = io:get_line(" "),
  case is_stop(Line) of
    false -> Line;
    true -> stop
  end.

modify(replace, State) ->
  modify(replace, State, input());
modify(append, State) ->
  modify(append, State, input());
modify(change, State) ->
  modify(change, State, input()).

modify(_, State, stop) ->
  State;
modify(replace, {File, Buffer, Pos}, Input) ->
  modify(replace, {File, replace(Buffer, Pos, Input), Pos+1}, input());
modify(append, {File, Buffer, Pos}, Input) ->
  modify(append, {File, insert(Buffer, Pos+1, Input), Pos+1}, input());
modify(change, {File, Buffer, Pos}, Input)
  when tuple_size(Buffer) == 0; Pos =< 0; Pos > tuple_size(Buffer) ->
  modify(append, {File, replace(Buffer, Pos, Input), Pos}, input());
modify(change, State, Input) ->
  modify(append, State, Input).

replace(Buffer, Pos, _)
  when tuple_size(Buffer) == 0; Pos =< 0; Pos > tuple_size(Buffer) ->
  Buffer;
replace(Buffer, Pos, Input) ->
  setelement(Pos, Buffer, Input).

insert(Buffer, Pos, Input) when Pos =< 0 ->
  erlang:insert_element(1, Buffer, Input);
insert(Buffer, Pos, Input) when Pos > tuple_size(Buffer) ->
  erlang:insert_element(tuple_size(Buffer) + 1, Buffer, Input);
insert(Buffer, Pos, Input) ->
  erlang:insert_element(Pos, Buffer, Input).

guard_position({File, Buffer, Pos}) when tuple_size(Buffer) == 0; Pos < 1 ->
  {File, Buffer, 1};
guard_position({File, Buffer, Pos}) when Pos > tuple_size(Buffer) ->
  {File, Buffer, tuple_size(Buffer)};
guard_position(State) ->
  State.

get_arg(String) when is_list(String) ->
  {Integer, _} = string:to_integer(String),
  case is_integer(Integer) andalso Integer > 0 of
    true -> Integer;
    _    -> 1
  end;
get_arg(_) -> 1.

position([Char|Tail], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  case Char of
    %% +, -, <number>
    43 -> {File, Buffer, Pos+1};
    45 -> {File, Buffer, Pos-1};
    _ -> {Integer, "\n"} = string:to_integer([Char] ++ Tail),
         {File, Buffer, Integer}
    end.

remove(N, {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  {File, erlang:delete_element(N, Buffer), Pos}.

delete([], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  remove(Pos, {File, Buffer, Pos});
delete([Char|Tail], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  case Char of
    %% *,
    42 -> {File, {}, Pos};
    _  -> remove(get_arg([Char] ++ Tail), {File, Buffer, Pos})
  end;
delete(N, {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  delete(Pos, Pos+N, {File, Buffer, Pos}).

delete(Current, End, State) when Current < End ->
  delete(Current+1, End, remove(Current, State));
delete(_, _, State) ->
  State.

search(_, Line, {File, Buffer, Pos}) when Line > tuple_size(Buffer) ->
  io:fwrite("not found~n"),
  {File, Buffer, Pos};
search(String, Line, {F, Buffer, Pos}) when tuple_size(Buffer) > 0, Line > 0 ->
  case string:str(element(Line, Buffer), String) of
    0 -> search(String, Line+1, {F, Buffer, Pos});
    _ -> {F, Buffer, Line}
  end.

search(String, {File, Buffer, Pos}) when is_list(String) ->
  search(string:strip(String, both, $\n), Pos+1, {File, Buffer, Pos});
search(_, State) ->
  io:fwrite("?~n"),
  State.

join({File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  {File, join(Pos, Buffer), Pos}.
join(Line, Buffer) when Line+1 =< tuple_size(Buffer) ->
  Concat = string:join([string:strip(element(Line, Buffer), right, $\n),
                        element(Line+1, Buffer)], ""),
  NewBuffer = setelement(Line, Buffer, Concat),
  erlang:delete_element(Line+1, NewBuffer);
join(_, Buffer) ->
  Buffer.

help() ->
  HelpString =
"erled -- erlang line editor, Finn O'leary\
Started on 2016-05-31. Current iteration: 2016-06-03_3.\
commands:\
  q, ?, w, p    -- quit, help, write file, print file.\
  a, c, r       -- append, change, replace.\
  Please note that append, change and replace all accept
  input until a single line with a `.` has been input.\

  d, d*, d<n>   -- delete line, file, <n> lines.\
  P, P<n>       -- print line, lines from current position.\
  /<s>, j       -- search for <s>, join next line to current.\
  g+, g-, g<n>  -- next line, prev line, go to line <n>.\
",
  io:fwrite(HelpString).

command(State) ->
  command(io:get_line(""), guard_position(State)).
command([Char|_Tail], State) ->
  case Char of
    %% q, w, c, a, r, p, P, g, d, /, j, ?, ...
    113 -> {ok, State};
    119 -> write_buffer(State);
     99 -> modify(change, State);
     97 -> modify(append, State);
    114 -> modify(replace, State);
    112 -> write_buffer(stdout, State);
     80 -> put_cursor(get_arg(_Tail), State);
    103 -> position(_Tail, State);
    100 -> delete(_Tail, State);
     47 -> search(_Tail, State);
    106 -> join(State);
     63 -> help(), State;
      _ -> io:fwrite("?~n"), State
    end.
```

On the whole I dislike the design, as I feel that I repeat some patterns rather too much. I also feel that the code is rather verbose. Could you give any advice on how to clean it up and perhaps make it idiomatic for Erlang code? I toyed with the idea of using gen_fsm, but it seemed like overkill for my needs at the time. I also attempted to use records at some point, but found I somehow ended up with more code than I started with (In part due to the `State#state.foo` syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should the code do?

Below are some corrections that I would do:

.1. Instead of:

```
{ok, Arg} = init:get_argument(f),
Name = lists:nth(1, lists:nth(1, Arg)),
main(Name).
```

Do:

```
{ok, [[Name, _], _]} = init:get_argument(f),
main(Name).
```

Does this fragment work correctly?

.2. Instead of:

```
modify(replace, State) ->
  modify(replace, State, input());
modify(append, State) ->
  modify(append, State, input());
modify(change, State) ->
  modify(change, State, input()).
```

Do:

```
modify(Action, State) ->
  modify(Action, State, input()).
```

.3. Instead of:

```
delete([], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  remove(Pos, {File, Buffer, Pos});
delete([Char|Tail], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  case Char of
    %% *,
    42 -> {File, {}, Pos};
    _  -> remove(get_arg([Char] ++ Tail), {File, Buffer, Pos})
  end;
delete(N, {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  delete(Pos, Pos+N, {File, Buffer, Pos}).
```

Do:

```
delete([], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  remove(Pos, {File, Buffer, Pos});
delete([42 = Char|Tail], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  {File, {}, Pos};
delete([Char|Tail], {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  remove(get_arg([Char] ++ Tail), {File, Buffer, Pos});
delete(N, {File, Buffer, Pos}) ->
  delete(Pos, Pos+N, {File, Buffer, Pos}).
```

Otherwise the code looks quite OK. If it looks repetitive then it's probably because the `State` and common tuples are being dragged along to all the functions. Some of it could also be down to the choice of data structures used to store data, i.e. why `Buffer` is a tuple and not a list? In Erlang it's much easier to manipulate variable-size data with lists than with tuples.